# Changing inner text value of tab through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, shiny

I'm learning Javascript right now, and attempting to change the text title of a particular tab. It's actually part of a larger Shiny dashboard project, but I want to add some custom functionality to a few tabs. Below are the tabs in question:

[image]

Simple enough. I first access my tabs in my Javascript file:

```
var tabScrub2 = $(document).find('[data-value="scrubTab2"]');
console.log(tabScrub2);
```

When I use Firefox's developer console, I see that the tab is an object:

[image]

Moreover, it looks like I need to change the `innerText` property of `0`, whatever this is, since that corresponds to the title of my tab (the `innerText` of `1` corresponds to the text inside `scrubTab2`). However, I'm not familiar with the actual object type being returned here:

[image]

Simply put, how the heck do I access and manipulate properties from this? And am I actually accessing an array? When I type in

```
var scrub2 = tabScrub2["1"];
console.log(scrub2);
```

I get an HTML element. I'm seen the `a` element in CSS and jQuery, but am not super familiar with how to manipulate its properties programmatically? How do I go about accessing and manipulating the `innerText` properties of this via Javascript? For instance, how would I hide `scrubTab2`, or change its title to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `jQuery` `eq` method to get the relevant `object index` from the `array`.

For an example

```
//Query and get first element.
var tabScrub2 = $(document).find('[data-value="scrubTab2"]:eq(0)');

//Hide
tabScrub2.hide();

//Change title
tabScrub2.attr("title", "New Title Text");
```

Lean more about jQuery `eq` here.
https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Since you use `jquery` selectors `tabScrub2[0]` returns the native `DOM` element instead of another `jQuery` object. Therefore the `hide` function won't work in that object since the native DOM element doesn't implement such type of functionality for an element. That's why you have to use `jQuery` pseudo selector as above. Because `hide` will only work with a `jQuery` object.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't think your syntax is correct. Do you mean `var tabScrub2 = $(document).find('[data-value="scrubTab2"]').eq(0)`?

Comment: Sorry , my mistake. I updated it to use pseudo selector. Your one is also correct

Comment: Thanks. Your answer does work great! I'll go ahead and accept, but could you provide a bit of insight into what I was seeing inside my Firefox console just so I can learn it? Is there a way to programmatically access and manipulate the set of matched elements? And what type data structure is this stored in? Would `tabScrub2["0"].hide()` be the same using my original code?

Comment: Since you use `jquery` selectors  `tabScrub2[0]` returns the native DOM element instead of another `jQuery` object. Therefore the `hide` function won't work in that object since the native DOM element doesn't implement such type of functionality for an element. That's why you have to use jQuery pseudo selector as above. Because `hide` will only work with a `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 2):

The first object you're seeing is jQuery's wrapper around the real DOM elements. It's not an actual array, but it does contain all of the elements that matched your query under zero-indexed properties (e.g. "0" and "1") which allows you to access to them via an array-like API (e.g. `tabScrub[1]`).

Your method of grabbing a node using `tabScrub2["1"]` is correct (see [this question in the jQuery FAQ](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)). It's more likely to see that done with a numeric key though (i.e. `tabScrub[1]`) because that matches the way you would access an element in a normal array.

As far as manipulating properties of the DOM node, the DOM's API is notoriously inconsistent and quirky (hence the need for things like jQuery in the first place). However, for your use case you can just assign a string to the innerText property directly (e.g. `tagScrub2[1].innerText = "Tab title"`). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a great resource if you're looking for reference material on other parts of the DOM.

A side note: if you're looking for a specific element you should use a query that will *only* match that element. It's generally a bad sign if you're grabbing extra elements and then accessing the element you want at a key other than `0`. If you're doing this then your code depends on other (potentially unrelated) nodes in the DOM existing before your node, and if/when you change those nodes your original code will break.

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted since I had just accepted a pretty good answer from another user moments before. For your side note, how would I access only that matching element in this case? On my console, the `id` and `name` properties are both empty strings, so I don't see how I can see `document.getElementById()`. I'm not sure if this is R Shiny functionality, since the actual UI and HTML output is rendered through an R script.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! I'm not familiar with R Shiny, but generally speaking you want to change the code that generates the HTML to add a unique id/class/data attribute that you can use as a hook for JavaScript. I would start by seeing if you can do that in Shiny.